# Python Script won't run against all files, and won't end when I hit Ctrl-C

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I'm new to Python, and I'm having a problem with executing some code with Watchdog.  The code  is supposed to copy files to their respective folders when they're modified or created.  It will work against one file, but then it quits if there are more files matching.  I also can't stop the program with Ctrl-C for some reason.  Full code below:

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

sourcepath='C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/'
sourcefiles = os.listdir(sourcepath)
destinationpath = 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/xls'
destinationpathcsv = 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/csv'
destinationpathtxt = 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/txt'
destinationpathpdf = 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/pdf'
path = sourcepath
event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()






def on_created(event):

    

    for file in sourcefiles:
            if os.path.exists(file):
                if file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.xlsx'):
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), os.path.join(destinationpath,file))
                if file.endswith('.csv'):
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), os.path.join(destinationpathcsv,file))
                    print("CSV file moved.")
                if file.endswith('.txt'):
                    print("TXT file moved")
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), os.path.join(destinationpathtxt,file))
                if file.endswith('.pdf'):
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), os.path.join(destinationpathpdf,file))


def on_modified(event):



    for file in sourcefiles:
            if os.path.exists(file):
                if file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.xlsx'):
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), os.path.join(destinationpath,file))
                if file.endswith('.csv'):
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), os.path.join(destinationpathcsv,file))
                if file.endswith('.txt'):
                    print("TXT file moved")
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), os.path.join(destinationpathtxt,file))
                if file.endswith('.pdf'):
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(sourcepath,file), os.path.join(destinationpathpdf,file))



if __name__ == "__main__":

    event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
    observer = Observer()
    observer.start()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.join()

    event_handler.on_created = on_created
    observer = Observer()
    observer.start()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.join()

    try:
        print("test")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

Comment: maybe first you should use `print()` (or module `logging`) to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: `listdir()` gives filenames without folder so you should use `os.path.join(..)` even when you check `os.path.exists(..)`

Comment: `join()` block code until you finish code - so putting `try/except` to catch `Ctrl+C` at the end is useless. You should rather put all code inside `try/except`

Comment: code could be simpler and more universal if you would keep paths as dictionary  `{".xls": 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/xls', ...}` because then you could use `for`-loop to check every extension. And you could add new extension to dictionary without changing code to work with other extensions.

Comment: you have the same code in `on_created` and `on_modified` so you could use one function. And I'm not sure if you need two observers. first `join()` may wait for end of first observer but you could use one observer with `.on_modified = my_function` and `.on_created = my_function`

Comment: you should use `listdir()` inside function to get all filenames when you create new file.

Comment: functions get `event` which have information `event.src_path`, `event.event_type` so it may no need to use `listdir()` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I resolve all problems but:

---

`listdir()` gives filenames without directory and you have to use `os.path.join()` even when you check `os.path.exists()`

```
if os.path.exists( os.path.join(sourcepath, file) ):
```

---

`listdir()` gives filenames only once and you have to use it inside `for`-loop to get new filenames.

```
def on_created(event):

    sourcefilenames = os.listdir(sourcepath)

    for filename in sourcefilenames:

        src = os.path.join(sourcepath, filename)

        if os.path.exists(src):

             # ... code ...


def on_modified(event):

    sourcefilenames = os.listdir(sourcepath)

    for filename in sourcefilenames:

        src = os.path.join(sourcepath, filename)

        if os.path.exists(src):

             # ... code ...
```

---

`.join()` blocks code and wait until you close program so it create first `Observer` and wait for its end before it create second `Observer` - but you could do all with one `Observer`

It seems you have the same code in `on_created` and `on_modified` so you could use one function for both situations

```
def move_it(event):
    sourcefilenames = os.listdir(sourcepath)

    for filename in sourcefilenames:

        src = os.path.join(sourcepath, filename)

        if os.path.exists(src):

             # ... code ...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()
    event_handler.on_modified = move_it
    event_handler.on_created  = move_it
    
    observer = Observer()
    observer.start()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, sourcepath, recursive=True)
    observer.join()
```

---

If you want to catch `Ctrl+C` then you should put all code in `try/except` (or at least put `join()` inside `try/except`).

I don't know what problem you have with `Ctrl+C` but it works for me on Linux.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()
        event_handler.on_modified = move_it
        event_handler.on_created  = move_it
        
        observer = Observer()
        observer.start()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, sourcepath, recursive=True)
        observer.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stopped by Ctrl+C')
```

---

One suggestion:

Code can be much simpler and more universal if you will use dictionary

```
{
   ".xls": "C:/.../xls", 
   ".xlsx": "C:/.../xls", 
   # ...
}
```

This way you can use `for`-loop to check all extensions. And you can always add new extension to dictionary without changing code in functions.

```
import os
import shutil
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

sourcepath = 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/'

destinationpath = {
    '.xls' : 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/xls',
    '.xlsx': 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/xls',    
    '.csv' : 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/csv',
    '.txt' : 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/txt',
    '.pdf' : 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/pdf',
}

def move_it(event):

    sourcefilenames = os.listdir(sourcepath)

    for filename in sourcefilenames:
        src = os.path.join(sourcepath, filename)
        if os.path.exists(src):
            for ext, dst in destinationpath.items():
                if filename.lower().endswith(ext):
                    print('move:', filename, '->', dst)
                    shutil.move(src, os.path.join(dst, filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()
        event_handler.on_modified = move_it
        event_handler.on_created  = move_it
        
        observer = Observer()
        observer.start()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, sourcepath, recursive=True)
        observer.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stopped by Ctrl+C')
```

---

**EDIT:**

`event` gives `event.src_path`, `event.event_type`, ect. and you could use it instead of `listdir()` to get path to file.

```
import os
import shutil
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

sourcepath = 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/'

destinationpath = {
    '.xls' : 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/xls',
    '.xlsx': 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/xls',    
    '.csv' : 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/csv',
    '.txt' : 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/txt',
    '.pdf' : 'C:/Users/bhart/Downloads/pdf',
}

def move_it(event):
    #print(dir(event))
    #print('event:', event)
    #print('event_type:', event.event_type)
    #print('is_directory:', event.is_directory)
    #print('src_path:', event.src_path)
    #print('key:', event.key)
    #print('----')

    if not event.is_directory:

        parts = os.path.split(event.src_path)
        #print('parts:', parts)
        filename = parts[-1]
        
        for ext, dst in destinationpath.items():
            if filename.lower().endswith(ext):
                shutil.move(event.src_path, os.path.join(dst, filename))
                print('move:', filename, '->', dst)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()
        event_handler.on_modified = move_it
        event_handler.on_created  = move_it
        #event_handler.on_moved    = move_it  # ie. rename (but this need to check `dest_path`)
        
        observer = Observer()
        observer.start()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, sourcepath, recursive=True)
        observer.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stopped by Ctrl+C')
```

Comment: I added example which uses information from `event`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It automatically moves as many files as needed now.  To mitigate the problem with Ctrl-C I changed the file from .py to .pyw so that it runs in the background without the console.  I appreciate the help! :)